# Is there a way to dismiss notifications using a keyboard shortcut in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, notifications

I'm talking about the notifications that appear in the bottom right corner and disappear by themselves in a few seconds. However, they sometimes can take up a lot of space and get in the way, which is bothersome. You can 'swipe' them away with your mouse to get rid of them faster, but is there a way to do the same using only the keyboard?

To be clear, I don't want to delete the notification from the Action Center, but rather to dismiss it for later viewing.

Comment: There isn't a native method to do that, no.  Depending upon how much time and effort you want to devote towards accomplishing this, [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/) can potentially be configured to do it.  People have already done similar things in previous versions of Windows, configuring AutoHotkey to [dismiss system tray notifications](https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=7305).

Comment: I see, I suspected as much. I may try to make an AutoHotkey script for this, in that case. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: THANK you very much for pointing that I can SWIPE it away! There is no "close" button, so how could I ever guess that?

Answer (score 14):

Hiding all currently displayed notifications for viewing them later works by opening and closing the Action Center. (Press [Win]+[A] two times)

When you need a total pause from notifications, you can open Action Center ([Win]+[A]) and enable Quiet Hours.

Also if a single app causes a bunch of messages you can reduce the maximum number of simultaniously displayed notifications per app to one:

Use the Windows key + I keyboard shortcut to open the Settings app.
Click System.
Click Notifications & actions.
Click on the source of notifications you want to regulate.
Choose the number of displayed notifications: [1, 3, 5, 10, 20] where 3 is standard.

Answer (score 7):

1. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>.
   This will move the focus to the notification.
2. Then, <kbd>Delete</kbd>, to dismiss it.

   - Previously, you had to press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Spacebar</kbd>

Found with some help from Winaero: [Dismiss Windows 10 Notification From Keyboard](https://winaero.com/blog/dismiss-windows-10-notification-from-keyboard/)