# Is there ANY WAY to completely dismiss a popup notification in windows 11?

Tags: windows-11, notifications, windows-11-v23h2

I'm on Windows 11 23H2, and to be clear, the behavior that I intend when I click the little cross on a popup notification is to completely dismiss it, not have it go to my notification area.

I assume the answer is no, since I have not seen any evidence to the contrary, but I just wanted to ask anyway (maybe Windows 11 has a way to do this that I don't know ).
This is something I've always hated about windows and I regularly look it up, but either not enough people care, or I'm the only one that wants this(?

Comment: Valid question, though I do not know if there is any way to prevent notifications from accumulating. At least one can dismiss multiple messages in the notification area *from the same source* by clicking on the X for the *source*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to dismiss notifications using a keyboard shortcut in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1161858/is-there-a-way-to-dismiss-notifications-using-a-keyboard-shortcut-in-windows-10) and especially the answer by user "Protector one".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it so notifications **only** show a pop-up, without creating an entry in the notification center, using the settings here for example:

[image: Settings > System > Notifications > app name]

> image from [How to make notifications less annoying on Windows 11](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-make-notifications-less-annoying-windows-11)

But there are no settings to change the behavior of the X button to dismiss notifications automatically.

Comment: This is basically what I had found that kinda achieves what I wanted, I guess you just can't. Thanks for answering anyways 

Answer (score 1):

There is not a general Turn Off Every Notification.  Some notifications are important (updates, restarts, etc.) and you need to know if your computer is going to restart imminently.

You can open a Notification and click on its properties that you do not wish to see this notification again. You will not see it again, and such notifications will *not* accumulate.

You can proactively go to Start, Settings, Systems, Notifications .

Scroll down and see Notifications from Apps and Other senders and disable what you do not want and enable what you do want.

Near the top, you can also turn off the general Notifications setting.

So: Notifications can most definitely be managed and you should manage them.

Some error and restart Notifications will always occur.

There are some notifications managed only by the App and not by Windows.  Adobe and WinZip are notorious for this and you must deal with the App, not Windows for these.